# How to use just Nickname instead of Full name on G+?

Tags: google-plus, privacy, google-account-profile

I'm following these Desktop [steps](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3298988) to add the nickname for my G+ profile, however I'm not able to use my nickname to display on comments.

For example going to some [Chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-check/ldopaogbegnhconlboidfjcmidndkbeg/reviews) and posting the comment using my Google account, I would like to see my nickname instead of full name.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably by using the "Display name as..." option where you create the nickname.

Unfortunately, Google doesn't give you that option. If you give yourself a nickname, you can display your name as

- John Doe
- John "Johnny Five" Doe
- John Doe (Johnny Five)

There is no option to just display "Johnny Five".

The other option is to [change your actual display name](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1228271), but that may be impractical for a couple of reasons.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks. I've tried to use nickname instead of Full name, but I've ended up with: [The nickname that you've chosen appears to violate the Google+ Names Policy.](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/4975/529)

Comment: I think Google's general recommendation is that Pages are the solution to this. Create a page with the nickname and post/comment/etc as the page.